# A quick algebra question derived from a solutions by substitution, differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

The question I have starts with the problem $$x\frac{dy}{dx}=y+\sqrt{x^2-y^2},\space x>0$$
After substituting in the values for $y$ and $dy$ and multiplying out 
$$xu+x^2\frac{du}{dx}=ux+\sqrt{x^2-u^2x^2}$$Then factoring both the $x$ and $u$ terms
$$x(u+x)\frac{du}{dx}=ux+x\sqrt{1-u^2}.$$
so my question is... 
$$x(u+x)\frac{du}{dx}=x(u+1)\sqrt{1-u^2}$$

Does this still work and if it does have I only  complicated it further.

Comment: I tested this with some constants to see for myself: $ux+5\sqrt{x^2-5x^3}=x(u+5)\sqrt{x^2-5x^3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$xu+x^2\frac{du}{dx}=ux+\sqrt{x^2-u^2x^2}$$Then factoring both the
>   $x$ and $u$ terms $$x(u+x)\frac{du}{dx}=ux+x\sqrt{1-u^2}$$

It should be $$x\left(u+x\frac{du}{dx}\right)=ux+x\sqrt{1-u^2},$$ which reduces to $$x\frac{du}{dx}=\sqrt{1-u^2}.$$ Can you complete now?

Comment: yeah, just gotta move the $\frac{du}{dx}$ around then integrate

Answer (score 2):

You should use that $xu=ux$ and simplify from the second formula to 
$$
x\frac{du}{dx}=\sqrt{1-u^2}
$$
which is separable. Thus you avoid the strange error in the last formula completely.